# Could a Mercedes sedan powered by 9,648 AA batteries reach 52 mph?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, automotive

Saturday Night Live's hilarious [Mercedes AA Class skit](https://www.nbc.com/saturday-night-live/video/new-mercedes/3021121) ([non-US link](https://iplayerhd.com/player/video/dae6a69a-adb1-4692-aaba-cff7e6bcd493)) showcases a Mercedes luxury sedan supposedly powered entirely by AA batteries:

[image]

But, as an engineer, I can only ask: **would a car powered by 9,648 AA batteries actually move**, and if yes, **can it reach the promised cruising speed of 52 mph**, even briefly?
(After all, it only takes a Tesla Model 3 about 5 seconds to accelerate from 0 to 60.)

Some vital statistics for your calculations:

- A [Mercedes A Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes-Benz_A-Class_(W177)) weighs about 1300 kg, including the internal combustion engine.
- A standard Duracell Coppertop AA 1.5V battery weighs 28g and promises around 10 minutes at 100 mA, or about 1 W for 1 hour ([full spec sheet](https://www.duracell.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/MN15USCT0122-A.pdf))
- 9,648 of these would weigh around 270 kg, so for our purposes we can probably figure that adding the batteries and removing the engine, gears etc will work out to 1,300 kg.

Comment: I suspect this isn't answerable without knowing details of the motor used and efficiency, unless you just mean "do the batteries contain enough energy to accelerate this much mass to this speed", which is a trivial calculation (the answer is yes, by about two orders of magnitude).

Comment: @Hearth The efficiency of a typical EV motor is around 85%.

Answer (score 5):

If we ignore almost all the details, assume everything is totally lossless, and just look at whether there's enough energy in the batteries to accelerate the car to the required speed, the answer is yes by about two orders of magnitude.

A 1300 kg mass moving at 52 mph has a total kinetic energy of $$\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{1}{2}·1300\ \mathrm{kg}·(52\ \frac{\mathrm{mi}}{\mathrm{h}})^2=97.57\ \mathrm{Wh}.$$

<sub>(Yes, I was surprised too, that feels too low! The math checks out, though.)</sub>

The batteries, which you posit can provide 1 W of energy for 1 hour, contain 1 Wh of energy each. This means the total battery energy is 9.648 kWh, or nearly one hundred times the energy that needs to be delivered to the car.

This calculation is slightly off, because I'm not considering the rotational kinetic energy of the wheels and drivetrain, which slightly increases the required kinetic energy. But with a 100× headroom, I think we can afford an additional percent or two.

Comment: Power loss due to frontal drag will be 0.6 x A x Cd x V^3 Watt (m^2, m/s). For say 5 m^2 and say 25 m/s and Cd of say 0.33 that's ABOUT ~16kW. So while the answer is still YES it does place constraints on the battery.  At 2A and say 1V at that load you get about 18 kW, which is enough, but closer than one may hope. An AA alkaline will give 1A reasonably happily, 2A OK, 5A depends on brand, 10A maybe briefly sometime. Adjust frontal area and Cd to suit. (eg 3 m^2  ~~= 11 kW). There are other losses but drag predominates.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, great points, +1, addressing the major power drain as being air friction. Combining with the kinetic energy calculated in the answer, it would be possible to estimate that not only that power could asymptotically reach that speed, but in how many seconds and for how long that myriad of AA could have energy to sustain it, assuming a given C capacity in Wh. Obviously it is just a conceptual exercise, as tire friction and other losses will affect the total running time, but probably not so big to impair on the final speed & drag.